# I want to convert my code in MVC codeigniter

Tags: php

I have very critical requirements from client. He wants to upload multiple choice questions. The questions to be uploaded may be text contents or it may be images. So there is One input field for question which can be textual or image and the same thing with other 4 options of the questions i. e. textual OR image. Means he may either type a question or simply upload an image file and at the same time; the answers of the same question are options which may be either text or images. Here is very critical issue that multiple file uploads with text data. I do program for the same in core php and it is working fine. I achieved this using base64 encoding. But I want the same code in CodeIgniter format. That is MVC architecture format.
Here is my code in core php.

```
<?php
$message = "Enter question ";

$this->load->database();
if (isset($_POST['no']) ){


$target_path = "./uploadIMG/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['que']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['que']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {


   // echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['que']['name']). 
   // $img_file = $target_path.$_FILES["que"]["name"];
$imgData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($target_path));
//$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($img_file).';base64,'.$imgData;
$que = $imgData;    

$a = "0";

} else{
$que = $_POST['que'];
$a = "1";

} 
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['opt1']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['opt1']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

  //  echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['opt1']['name']). 
    $img_file1 = $_FILES["opt1"]["name"];
$imgData1 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($target_path));
//$src1 = 'data: '.mime_content_type($img_file1).';base64,'.$imgData;
$opt1 = $imgData1;  
$b = $a . "|"."0";

} else{
$opt1 = $_POST['opt1'];
$b = $a . "|"."1";
} 

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['opt2']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['opt2']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

    //echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['opt2']['name']). 
    $img_file2 = $_FILES["opt2"]["name"];
$imgData2 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($target_path));
//$src2 = 'data: '.mime_content_type($img_file2).';base64,'.$imgData;
$opt2 = $imgData2;  
$c = $b . "|"."0";

} else{
$opt2 = $_POST['opt2'];
$c = $b . "|"."1";
} 
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['opt3']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['opt3']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

    //echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['opt3']['name']). 
    $img_file3 = $_FILES["opt3"]["name"];
$imgData3 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($target_path));
//$src3 = 'data: '.mime_content_type($img_file3).';base64,'.$imgData;
$opt3 = $imgData3;  
$d = $c . "|"."0";
} else{
$opt3 = $_POST['opt3'];
 $d = $c . "|"."1";
} 


$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['opt4']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['opt4']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

    //echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['opt4']['name']). 
    $img_file4 = $_FILES["opt4"]["name"];
$imgData4 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($target_path));
//$src4 = 'data: '.mime_content_type($img_file4).';base64,'.$imgData;
$opt4 = $imgData4;  
$e = $d . "|"."0";
} else{
$opt4 = $_POST['opt4'];
$e = $d . "|"."1";

} 


$no = $_POST['no'];
$ans= $_POST['ans'];
$expl=$_POST['expl'];
//echo " QUESTION DATA      " .$que. "<br>";//getcwd()

//echo " Answer DATA        " .$opt1. "<br>";//getcwd()

//echo " Answer Format        " .$e. "<br>";//getcwd()


$target_path = "/uploads/";

//$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 



 $q_code=$this->session->userdata('question_code');

 //echo "No1 " . $no . "";
        $query = "INSERT INTO question (question_no, question, option1, option2, option3, option4, answer, explaination, layout,question_code) VALUES ('$no', '$que', '$opt1','$opt2','$opt3','$opt4','$ans','$expl','$e','$q_code')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        //echo "No1 " . $query . "";
        //echo "No2  " . $$result . "";
         //$msg = "question created Successfully.";
        if($result){

            //echo "No1 " . $$result . "";
            $message = "question created Successfully.";
            echo " Question created Successfully.  " . $result . "";
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "question not created please enter valid question no. ";
            echo " Question not created please enter valid question no.  " . $result . "";
        }

    }

 }?>
```